# DjangoCMS 3 Filter Available Plugins

Tags: django, django-cms

In the [DjangoCMS3 documentation](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/support-3.0.x/reference/configuration.html#cms-placeholder-conf) it says you can configure DjangoCMS behavior using CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF in your settings. For instance:

> CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
>       'right-column': {
>           'plugins': ['TextPlugin', 'PicturePlugin'],
>            ...

This would make TextPlugin and PicturePlugin to be the only two plugins available inside any placeholder called "right-column".

It works, but what if I want this restriction to apply to ALL placeholders??

Thanks!

Comment: Edit: Without removing the plugins from INSTALLED_APPS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove plugins you don't need from `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Alternatively, in an app **after** all plugin apps in `INSTALLED_APPS` in either `cms_plugins.py` or `models.py` you can use `cms.plugin_pool.plugin_pool.unregister_plugin` to remove them from the pool:

```
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from unwanted_plugin_app.cms_plugins import UnwantedPlugin

plugin_pool.unregister_plugin(UnwantedPlugin)
```

Comment: Yes, I know this but I can't solve it this way because of dependencies between django apps.

Comment: That makes sense, you can instead use ``cms.plugin_pool.plugin_pool.unregister_plugin`` manually, see edited answer.